# Best way to create custom android button

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new at Android UI development and was curious to know if anyone had any simple approaches to creating a button with an image on the top, and some text with a solid background near the bottom of the button. What would be your approach to this?

I have considered creating a button with an image background, and then placing a label with the text 'Send' with a solid background color directly underneath the button. However, I assume this may render differently and not line up properly on different devices/versions of Android.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically create a layout with your image, bar and label (in a layout file..) and then you use the `<include>` tag to make that "button" accessible in other xml layouts.

You can just use regular `OnClickListener`'s for layouts.

Answer (score 1):

For this, I would create a linearLayout with an ImageView(if I have that arrow image) and a TextView underneath it. Can set the onClickListener either on the layout or the ImageView or the TextView. If you want an effect like a ripple you can always add a background with a custom style.